# Pull website text from one site and display it on another

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, string, pull

Hi I am trying to pull this string from courseweb.hopkinsschools.org and display it on my own asp.net application. I have been looking for a long time for a tutorial but nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Picture of String needed:
[String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpD4l.png)

Comment: How often is this string potentially changing? If it doesn't change often you're waisting a lot of time sending a request off to another server, waiting for a response, then processing it. You could just store it in a database or config file until it changes, then change it manually.

Comment: This is just an example of what I will be pulling. I would like to pull the list of the classes you are in. But to do this I need to be able to at first pull any text.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pull from moodle?

Comment: @AdamSchiavone Yes I am trying to pull from moodle

Comment: Please make sure your question aligns with accepted answer - right now it is really broad "Search for tutorials" (which is off-topic on SO) and have absolutely nothing to do with accepted answer.

Comment: Your right @AlexeiLevenkov It does not I am still looking for an answer to what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

When I started doing work with websites and interfacing with other websites, I originally wanted to do what you're talking about, reading the text from pages, because thats how we as people interface with computers and websites.

But that is not how computers should ever interface with other websites unless absolutely necessary.

Moodle has an API for such things like course management. Its kind of difficult to find information on, but its called Moodle Web Services if I remember quickly. I'll add a link back if I can find it.

What these will do is let you access moodle in a computer friendly way, ie. a way your computer can easily understand, instead of trying to read webpages.

**Edit**

Here are some resources to get you started:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services

https://code.google.com/p/mnet-csharp/

https://delog.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/integrating-a-c-app-with-moodle-using-xml-rpc/

https://delog.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/integrating-c-app-with-moodle-2/

Comment: Thank you! You have been very helpful.

Comment: Do I need access to admin accout to use this? As I do not. @AdamSchiavone

Comment: Probably. Maybe. Partially. I'm no expert in the moodle api, but to set up web services I would venture a guess that you need admin, but the client would not need to be an admin as it would only have access to its own account's information